# Flutter exact lifecycle equivalents to onResume / onPause on Android and viewWillAppear / viewDidDisappear on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, lifecycle

I've seen this asked before, but the questions are always subsets of functionality. I'm looking for *exact* equivalent life cycle events. And I can be more specific.

The ones I'm aware that exist in Flutter widgets are

- `onCreate`/`viewDidLoad` = `initState`
- `onDestroy`/`viewDidUnload` = `dispose`

These are the life cycle events I'd like to know about (for the **currently visible widget/route**, not the entire app):

###### `onResume` / `viewWillAppear` getting fired on the currently visible widget when

1. Internal nav (navigating around within the app)

   a.  You push the route/widget onto the stack

   b.  You navigate back to the route/widget (that was already on the back of nav stack)
2. External nav (backgrounding and foregrounding the app)

   a.  You open the app from the background (and the route/widget is the one being displayed to the user)

   b.  You turn the screen on (power button) and the app was already open

###### `onPause` / `viewDidDisappear` getting fired **on the currently visible widget** when

1. Internal nav (navigating around within the app)

   a.  You navigate away from a widget/route going forward

   b.  You navigate away from the widget by dismissing it / going backward in the stack
2. External nav (backgrounding and foregrounding the app)

   a.  You background the app (and the route/widget is the one being displayed to the user)
   b.  You turn the screen off (power button) with the app open

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've found a few solutions, each with its own pros and cons. The one that answers this question the best is [FocusDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector).

## Best Pick

##### [FocusDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector) (Edson Bueno)

FocusDetector handles all the cases covered in the original question. Instead of overrides (like initState() and dispose()), you supply callback functions to a wrapping widget called `FocusDetector`. The two relevant callbacks are:

- `onFocusGained` = `onResume`
- `onFocusLost` = `onPause`
- Cons

  - Isn’t maintained by Flutter or Google (but it uses `VisibilityDetector` and `WigetBindingObserver` under the hood)
  - The default `VisibilityDetectorController.updateInterval` is 500ms which means the events get fired somewhat late.

Borrowing the style from one of my [favorite posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969161/1759443):

[image: iOS, Android, and Flutter Life Cycle]

#### Example Widget

```dart
class PageState extends State<Page> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    log("onCreate / viewDidLoad / initState");
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      layoutComplete();
    });
  }

  // Bonus one I've found helpful, once layout is finished
  void layoutComplete() {
    log("onActivityCreated / viewDidLoad / layoutComplete");
  }

  void viewWillAppear() {
    log("onResume / viewWillAppear / onFocusGained");
  }

  void viewWillDisappear() {
    log("onPause / viewWillDisappear / onFocusLost");
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    log("onDestroy / viewDidUnload / dispose");
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FocusDetector(
      onFocusGained: viewWillAppear,
      onFocusLost: viewWillDisappear,
      child: Text('Rest of my widget'),
      );
  }
}
```

---

## Other options

##### [RouteObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteObserver-class.html) (Flutter)

- `didPush` = `onResume` current screen is pushed on
- `didPopNext` = `onResume` current screen is being navigated back to
- `didPop` = `onPause` dismissing current page / going back
- `didPushNext` = `onPause` navigating forward to a new page
- Cons:

  - Doesn’t cover use-case (2), backgrounding then foregrounding the app

##### [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) (Flutter)

- `AppLifecycleState.resumed` = The app is visible and responding to user input
- `AppLifecycleState.paused` = The app is not visible and not responding to user input
- Cons:

  - Isn’t widget/route specific (for external nav (2))
  - Doesn’t cover use-case (1), navigating between pages

##### [VisibilityDetector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) (Google)

- `onVisibilityChanged` (visibility == 1) = `onResume`
- `onVisibilityChanged` (visibility == 0) = `onPause`
- Cons:

  - Doesn’t cover use-case (2), backgrounding then foregrounding the app

Comment: You can improve the `updateInterval` issue by calling `VisibilityDetectorController.instance.updateInterval = 250;` on app start.

Comment: A great write-up and looks like a great solution, but not compatible with latest version of Google mobile ads. Receive error: 'Because focus_detector >=2.0.1 depends on visibility_detector ^0.2.2 and google_mobile_ads 2.2.0 depends on visibility_detector ^0.3.3, focus_detector >=2.0.1 is incompatible with google_mobile_ads

Comment: Have you tried dependency override? https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides
    
"dependency_overrides:
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3"
    
If that doesn't work, this should: https://github.com/EdsonBueno/focus_detector/issues/12#issuecomment-1187296367

Comment: This `FocusDetector`is a great solution, it is terrible that these methods aren't part of the framework. I'm even wondering how people are developing apps without these.

Comment: Thanks for this meticulous answer, so many people don't even read the question to tell it is use-case-1 or use-case-2, and they just give solutions right away!