How to refresh screen when user comes from background after a duration in flutter
I want to implement a global widget which handles the app state.
What i want to do is suppose i am on home screen of the application and now i put the app in background.
Now lets suppose if i re - opens the app and app comes in foreground and the time difference between app background and foreground is more than 30 minutes the i want to refresh home screen.
This should happens if i implemented that global widget in any other screen , lets say cart screen.
Please help me with the code in flutter

You can use WidgetBindingObserver on your most parent widget to notify about lifecycle state of the app, once it paused you can store the time then when resumed you can calculate the AFK time - the implementation details explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53128589/5055519

Can you try checking AppLifecycleState.resumed in didChangeAppLifecycleState() ?
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    _refreshData();
  }
}



Use WidgetsBindingObserver to notify when app state change (go background, foreground...)
Write data date time (to local storage) when app go to background
Get this data when app is back to foreground then compare

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreenState> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); // <--------
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this); // <--------
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    // check when app go foreground
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      final lastTimeGoBackground = getLastTimeGoBackgroundFromLocalStorage();
      final now = DateTime.now();
      if (now.isAfter(lastTimeGoBackground) && now.difference(lastTimeGoBackground).inMinutes >= 30) {
        // do your stuff here
      }
    }

    // write data date time when app go background
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      final now = DateTime.now();
      setLastTimeGoBackgroundFromLocalStorage(now);
    }
  }
}

